# Placing panels with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jcombobox

I have a GUI with a `JPanel` and this panel adds 2 more panels. So I want one of this two panels to be in the highest quarter of the frame with a `JComboBox` and the other should be  in the other 3 quarters of the frame and has a `JTable` in it.  But with `setBounds` method I can't place them right I think because of the table.

If someone already had the same problem and could help me, that would be great.

Comment: use IDE gui builder it will solve about 90% of your problems regarding gui building

Comment: @MaciejCygan at the price of introducing just the same (if you are lucky) amount of trouble :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but give this a try.

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
int x = getWidth();
int y = getHeight() * 0.25;
int y2 = getHeight() * 0.75;
p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y);
p1.add(yourFirsPanel);

JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y2);

JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p3.add(p1, BorderLayout(NORTH));
p3.add(p2, BorderLayout(CENTER));
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (**Yes.**)  - OP Provide ASCII art of the GUI (or a drawing) as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: @JUNGE not everthing that appears to solve a problem is a real solution :-) So, don't, your layout most probably will blow on the slightest change. Instead, use a suitable LayoutManager.